# Hadoop : Yarn and local memory usage

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

If we reserve 80% of memory for yarn, and then for some reason lets say memory leak for example, the os and local programs consumed 50% of memory.

Does yarn will be aware that there is only 50% for him ? whats the impact for the newly submitted applications ?

Answer (score 0):

YARN doesn't monitor the OS for available memory.  It's run as a normal process like everything else.  So the OS will do what it does whenever more memory is asked for than is available.

RE: MapReduce, most MR jobs typically use far less memory than they need so in most cases a local process over-consuming memory will not cause any problems.  YARN developers have noticed this underutilization pattern and have enabled a feature [Opportunistic Containers](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/OpportunisticContainers.html) to maximize node efficiency.

Comment: any ref plz or a simple test ?

Comment: It depends on the OS.  Are you running Linux?

Comment: used OS is RHEL

Comment: Look at `stress` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/stress) to simulate taking available memory.